# Why does WindowManager.getdefaultdisplay() warn of a null pointer exception?

Tags: android, android-studio

Below is some code I have in Android Studio. Android Studio warns that getdefaultdisplay() may throw a null pointer exception.

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
actions = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, when I flip line 3 and 2... it no longer warns. The lines are unrelated though... why is this the case?

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
actions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any method that warns `NullPointerException` are marked as `@Nullable`, which means that it might return `null`, so you need to check the result of the `getDefaultDisplay()` method before using it in order to be sure that the code will not crash because of `NullPointerException`

```
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay()
if(display != null) {
    // do what you need here
}
```

Comment: Why does Android Studio hide the warning when I add a line between the two?

Comment: because `LayoutInflater.from(context)` will call `getSystemService(...)` which is called in getting the windowManager, and this method if did not return null, then android studio will be sure that the first line did not return null because it's the same method.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Khalid.

Comment: Welcome, Any Time :)